# Syntax to query LDAP over SSL

Tags: ssl, ldap

I was able to query LDAP over port 636 with the below.  How do I modify it so I can query the below AD path:
"OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,OU=ABC PROD,DC=Abc,DC=com"

=============================================================
SELECT  top 900 * FROM OpenQuery (

ADSI,
'SELECT *
FROM ''LDAP://ABC.com:636''
WHERE objectClass = ''User''
')

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Doing trial an error, this seems to work.  Thank you.

SELECT  top 900 * FROM OpenQuery (
ADSI,
'SELECT *
FROM ''LDAP://abc.com:636/OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,OU=ABC PROD,DC=abc,DC=com''

WHERE objectClass = ''User''
'
)